# What does the imported libraries {} and {} both cannot be unnamed mean?

Tags: dart, webstorm

I have the following three imports from my application to a test class

```
import 'package:grocery_totes/domain/grocery_list.dart';
import 'package:grocery_totes/api/grocery_list_controller.dart';
import 'package:grocery_totes/repository/repository.dart';
```

The bottom two get highlighted by my IDE (WebStorm) with the error:

```
 the imported libraries {} and {} both cannot be unnamed
```

What causes this? All three files contain only a single class that are uniquely named.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this out.

I must add a `library myLibrary;` to the top of each file.

Comment: Actually you don't need to add it to each file. If you don't, the library gets the default library name (empty string). What you can't do is two libraries with the same name. So if you have a one-file Dart script you don't need the library declaration. When you start importing other libraries you need to add a library declaration to all but one file.